# Removing a Preceding Backslash from Apostrophes

Tags: php

When I add a comment using the variable below, apostrophes are printed with a backslash in front of them.  How can I get rid of the backslashes?

Thanks in advance,

John

Example of printed result:

My roommate\'s brother\'s ex-girlfriend\'s aunt drive a Toyota.

```
$comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

```
Note: If magic_quotes_gpc is enabled, first apply stripslashes() to the data. Using this function on data which has already been escaped will escape the data twice.
```

Answer (score 3):

[**`mysql_real_escape_string()`**](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) is adding backslashes, so you can inject your string safely into an SQL query *-- this is acting as a protection against [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)*.

But **this function should only be used when you want to build an SQL query** -- not when you want to output something.

When you want to output a string to an HTML page, you'll generally use [`htmlspecialchars`](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) or [`htmlentities`](http://fr.php.net/htmlentities), to prevent [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

If you already have some backslashes before calling `mysql_real_escape_string()`, it might be because of [**Magic Quotes**][6] -- if so, you might want to first call [`stripslashes()`][7] on the input you get from the user, to not duplicate the backslashes.

Comment: Thanks.  How could I use htmlspecialchars() to get rid of backslashes for outputs?

Comment: htmlspecialchars won't get rid of slashes, it will simple encode < as &lt; and stuff like that. slashes are removed by using stripslashes :)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that exactly what `mysql_real_escape_string` is supposed to do? If you're still seeing the slashes after inserting the data into the database and fetching it back, make sure the `magic_quotes_gpc` server option is turned off.